# import AWS iOS SDK cause architecture error

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, architecture, arm64

I've downloaded the latest [AWS iOS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/) and added several frameworks (without copy) manually into my project.

Without further ado I got errors with a simple build:
[image]

Here's my architecture settings:
[image]

Since I understand none of the errors...
any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the [Set Up the SDK for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) section of AWS Mobile SDK for iOS Developer Guide. You are not linking `libsqlite3.dylib`, `libz.dylib`, and `SystemConfiguration.framework`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this parameters:
[image]

Then, it is a good practice using `cocoapods`. AWS github has a great guide on how to implement their libraries (check the link):

[Amazon Web Services SDK iOS Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios)

Comment: not working... I did not use cocoapods because it cause some other errors in my case

Comment: Do u use `Product/Clean` before testing everything?

Comment: yup I did, and the parameters you provided was actually my original set... I changed that to NO due to another answer to a similar question

Comment: Have you linked binary with libraries? In `Build Phases / Link Binary With Libraries` add all the libraries you have in your project explorer